# R stars: st_as_stars/read_stars kills x&y raster values; how to convert to stars?

Tags: r, type-conversion, raster, r-stars

I have a `raster` read in & given a `CRS` with:

```
x <- raster::raster("originalobject")
dataCRS <- readRDS(paste0(crsloc, "CRS.Rds"))
raster::crs(x) <- dataCRS
```

It has an `x` extent of roughly -+29000, `CRS` is `AEQD`, `3857`. Its data plot fine. I want to convert it to a `stars` object to plot it as a surface in a `ggmap` plot using `geom_stars`.

However if I try to convert the `raster` object to a `stars` object:

```
surfaceUD <- stars::st_as_stars(x)
```

`x` & `y` have wkt-style 'input' crs attributes but no unknown 'wkt' attributes, and `x` & `y` values are both `NULL`. The data in the `raster` ("All_Rasters_Scaled_Weighted_UDScaled") are still present:

[[image: image1]]]

If I instead convert and set a CRS:

```
surfaceUD <- stars::st_as_stars(x) %>% sf::st_set_crs(3857)
```

`x` & `y` have 'input' crs attributes as "EPSG:3857", possibly having lost the lat/lon offsets? The 'wkt' attributes are now populated, and `x` & `y` values are both still `NULL`. The data in the raster are still present.

[[image: [image2]]]

Full `x` attribute info in case it's useful:

```
attr(surfaceUD, "dimensions")$x
```

> $from 1
>
> $to 293
>
> $offset -29238.71
>
> $delta 200
>
> $refsys Coordinate Reference System:   User input: EPSG:3857    wkt:
>
> PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
>
> ```
> BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
>     ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
>         MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
>         MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
>         MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
>         MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
>         MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
>         MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
>         MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
>         ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
>         ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
>     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
>         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
>     ID["EPSG",4326]],
> CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
>     METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
>         ID["EPSG",1024]],
>     PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
>         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
>         ID["EPSG",8801]],
>     PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
>         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
>         ID["EPSG",8802]],
>     PARAMETER["False easting",0,
>         LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
>         ID["EPSG",8806]],
>     PARAMETER["False northing",0,
>         LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
>         ID["EPSG",8807]]],
> CS[Cartesian,2],
>     AXIS["easting (X)",east,
>         ORDER[3],
>         LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
>     AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
>         ORDER[3],
>         LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
> USAGE[
>     SCOPE["Web mapping and visualisation."],
>     AREA["World between 85.06°S and 85.06°N."],
>     BBOX[-85.06,-180,85.06,180]],
> ID["EPSG",3857]]
> ```
>
> $point NA
>
> $values NULL

Possibly the `$offset` is the same as `+lat_0=25.6871`? I'm not sure that the offset is a problem though.

I also tried read_stars on "originalobject" but that had the same effect as `surfaceUD <- stars::st_as_stars(x)`.

The stars intro [says](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars1.html) `read_stars` "will cause a loss of certain properties (cell size, reference system, vector geometries)". Is this the cause?

Is there any way to convert from `raster` to `stars` without losing all this vital info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `CRS` format from the `sp` package in `st_set_crs` from the `sp` package, you have to use `crs` from the `raster` package. `raster::crs(x) <- dataCRS` can accept a `sp::CRS` object, but `sp::st_set_crs` CAN'T accept a `sp::CRS` object.

Incredibly unintuitively, you have to use the `proj4string` minor function of `raster::CRS`:

```
x <- stars::read_stars(x) # x is an asc raster
dataCRS <- readRDS(paste0(crsloc, "CRS.Rds")) # load CRS from file
sf::st_crs(x) <- proj4string(dataCRS) # set CRS
```